# Set hide dev tools popup in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I start debugging every time I get a pop up about the dev tools. Would like to disable it. How can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Command Palette (⇧⌘P) with **Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)**, and add the below snippet:

```
{
    "dart.openDevTools": "never",
}
```

Save it and the DevTools popup will not automatically show up from now on.